# How to set an AJAX callback for my drop down list select in my form?

Tags: views, ajax

I am about to create a filter views handler extended from views_handler_filter_string
(you can see the class under views/handlers), so I have to override my method value_form to create a new value form form my filter handler.

```
function value_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $countries = _prepare_countries_list();
    $selected_country = isset($form_state['values']['value']['country'])?$form_state['values']['value']['country']:key($countries);

    $values = array(
        'country' => array(
            '#type'    => 'select',
            '#title'   => t('Country'),
            '#options' =>$countries,
            '#ajax'    => array(
                'callback' => 'country_state_dependent_dropdown_callback',
                'wrapper'  => 'dropdown-states',
            ),
        ),
        'state' => array(
            '#type'    => 'select',
            '#title'   => t('State'),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-states">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#options' => _country_state_get_second_dropdown_options($selected_country),
        ),
    );
    $form['value'] = $values;
    return $form;
}
```

I am trying here to set an ajax callback for my drop down list select. Usually we implement our callback function and we return $form['element'], but in my case it gives no result.

Anyone who has tried to override the value_form before to add some AJAX able to help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. You are trying to update the options in your second select element , every-time your first select element changes it's value?

Comment: have you answered already your question?Why did you post your supposed "reply" in the answer section? :)

Comment: iam sorry, i didnt answer it yet. i was mistake

Comment: yes you are right. so with drupal form i can handle it but in this case when overrding value_form(&$form, &$form_state) method of my views/handlers/views_handler_filter_string.inc.php class it's complicated

Comment: http://w3shaman.com/article/creating-ajax-dropdown-drupal-7

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but at least, you get the logic. I'm sorry if I edited your coding style convention.

```
function value_form(&$form, &$form_state)
{
    $form = array();

    $countries = _prepare_countries_list();
    $selected_country = isset($form_state['values']['country'])?$form_state['values']['country']:key($countries);

    // Country dropdown list
    $form['country'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Country'),
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $countries,
        '#ajax' => array(
            'event'=>'change',
            'callback' =>'country_state_dependent_dropdown_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'dropdown-states',
        ),
    ); 

    // Wrapper for state dropdown list
    $form['state_wrapper'] = array(
        '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-states">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ); 


    // State dropdown list
    $form['state_wrapper']['state'] = array(
        '#title' => t('State'),
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => _country_state_get_second_dropdown_options($selected_country),
    ); 

    return $form;
}


/**
* Function for handling ajax request
*/
function country_state_dependent_dropdown_callback($form, $form_state){
    return $form['state_wrapper'];
}
```